# pandas - efficient application for multiple blocks of drop, rename, and between?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have multiple blocks of codes that i wish to scale down, is there a more efficient way to shortening this?

Here's an example of part of the block of codes

```
tra = tra.rename(columns = {'1':'T1'})
tra = tra.rename(columns = {'2':'T2'})
tra = tra.rename(columns = {'3':'T3'})

tra1 = tra[tra['range'].between(1,1.9, inclusive=True)]
tra2 = tra[tra['range'].between(2,2.9, inclusive=True)]
tra3 = tra[tra['range'].between(3,3.9, inclusive=True)]

tra1 = pd.DataFrame(tra1.drop(['range'],axis=1))
tra2 = pd.DataFrame(tra2.drop(['range'],axis=1))
tra3 = pd.DataFrame(tra3.drop(['range'],axis=1))

dis = dis.rename(columns = {'1':'D1'})
dis = dis.rename(columns = {'2':'D2'})

dis1 = dis[dis['range'].between(1,1.9, inclusive=True)]
dis2 = dis[dis['range'].between(2,2.9, inclusive=True)]

dis1 = pd.DataFrame(dis1.drop(['range'],axis=1))
dis2 = pd.DataFrame(dis2.drop(['range'],axis=1))
```

many thanks

For better understanding, the above are conditions for filtering between DFs which i had concated and below is part of the code i used to filter between DFs:

```
dis1['marker'] = 1
dis1 = pd.merge(tra1, dis1, on=['distance'], how='left')
dis1 = dis1[dis1['marker'].notnull()]
dis1 = pd.DataFrame(dis1.drop(['marker'],axis=1))
dis1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
dis1.head()
```

is there anymore information i should add to better facilitate the question?

Comment: Those between blocks are a little odd. Do you want bins like [1, 2), [2, 3), [3, 4), or do you mean to exclude points between `(2.9, 3.0)`?

Comment: if i understood you correctly, tra[tra['range'].between(3,3.9, inclusive=True)] is condition for filtering different section of the code of the DF. fyi, i'm filtering using multiple DFs